# pygame pygame.display.update() function decreases fps

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

We're making a small game in python but we have some problems with the pygame pygame.display.update() function. Its dramaticly decreasing our fps rate (40.000 to 27) while we're only redrawing a single sprite. (Rendering the background and the player doesnt really matter, it doesnt drop more)

Are we doing something wrong or is it just python being not that fast?

```
def render():
  screen.blit(background, (0,0))
  fred.draw()

  pygame.display.update(fred.pos)
```

FPS 28

```
def render():
  #screen.blit(background, (0,0))
  fred.draw()

  pygame.display.update(fred.pos)
```

FPS 31

as you can see removing the background from the render process does only increase the fps a bit. but still a drop from 40.000 to 28 when only redrawing 1 or 2 sprites?

Full code:

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 1024, 500
fps = 60
speed = 10

beginTime = time.clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
background = pygame.image.load('/pathtosprite/background.png').convert()

class Fred(object):
  strength = 0
  pos = 0
  sprite = 0

  def __init__(self, strength, position):
    self.sprite = pygame.image.load('/pathtosprite/fred.png').convert()
    self.strength = strength
    self.pos = pygame.Rect(10, 10, position[0], position[1])

  def draw(self):
    screen.blit(self.sprite, self.pos)

  def walk(self, direction):
    self.pos = self.pos.move(direction)

def tick(): #doet de berekeningen per stap
  lastTime = time.clock()
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

  if keys[K_UP]:
    fred.walk([0,-speed])
  if keys[K_DOWN]:
    fred.walk([0,speed])
  if keys[K_RIGHT]:
    fred.walk([speed,0])
  if keys[K_LEFT]:
    fred.walk([-speed,0])

  render()


def render(): #updatet het scherm
  screen.blit(background, (0,0))
  fred.draw()

  pygame.display.update(fred.pos)

def run(): #zorgt dat fps gehandhaafd blijft
  startTime = time.clock()
  ticks = 0
  frames = 0

  while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    now = time.clock()
    if now-startTime > 1/fps:
      ticks += 1
      print(ticks/(now-beginTime))
      startTime = now
      tick()

fred = Fred(10000000, (10, 10))    
run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `from pygame.locals import *` means `time` refers to pygame's time module instead of the standard library time module.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You would have to write `from pygame import *` to import the `time` module (please don't do this).

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

^is a bit faster than update.
Also I recommend using delta time for moving if you add it to the game.